# connect codeigniter to database oracle server

Tags: oracle, codeigniter

i have some problems to connect between codeigniter 3 to database oracle server in other machine

i've tried 3 times to connect like this :

## 1

```
$active_group = 'oracle';  
$conn = "(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.0.2)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = xyz)))";
...
'hostname' => $conn,
'dbdriver' => 'oci8',
...
```

and get error *"You have specified an invalid database connection group (oracle) in your config/database.php file."*

## 2

```
$active_group = 'default';
$conn = "(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.0.2)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = xyz)))";
...
'hostname' => $conn,
'dbdriver' => 'oci8',
...
```

and get error *"Message: Use of undefined constant OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS - assumed 'OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)"
dan "Message: Call to undefined function oci_connect()"
"Filename: C:.........\database\drivers\oci8\oci8_driver.php"*

## 3

i change dbdriver to

```
 'dbdriver' => 'oci8_12c',
```

and i get error *"Invalid DB driver"*

---

any idea how to connect using codeigniter in the different machine?

thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

First of check DB driver https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-56487.html

My database.php for oracle was like this

```
$tns = "
(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = YOUR_IP)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = YOUR_SID)
    )
  )
       ";
$db['oracle']['hostname'] = $tns;
```

You used `$this->load->database('oracle',true);` this should be assigned to a variable as you used 2nd parameter true. like this

```
$oracle_db=$this->load->database('oracle',true);//connected with oracle
$mysql_db=$this->load->database('default',true);//connected with mysql
```

Comment: A side comment about the connection string syntax: SID is very old.  Most Oracle installations will use SERVICE_NAME which can then alternatively be used in Easy Connect syntax like `$tns = 'your_ip:your_port/service_name'`